# Upgrading database on app update

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-8, windows-store-apps, sqlite-net

I am developing a Windows Store App that uses **SQLite for Windows Runtime Extension** and **sqlite-net library** to store data in a local SQLite database. This database is created in `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path` path.
Everything works like it should and I guess I will not have problems when submiting.

#### Question 1

But what will happen when I change the app, submit again and the user updates it?
Will database file be deleted? Will the user lost his data?

#### Question 2

Will I be able to use the old database and upgrade it between app versions?

I know how to do it when developing Android apps but this Windows Store Update process is new to me and I am afraid of doing some mistake that makes me unable to recover users data. If someone has already gone through it tell me how it works please.

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application data persists over updates; it would only be deleted if the user uninstalled the application.  From [Accessing app data with the Windows Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx):

> The system manages the data stores for an app, ensuring that they are kept isolated from other apps and other users. The system also preserves the contents of these data stores when the user installs an update to your app and removes the contents of these data stores completely and cleanly when your app is uninstalled.

Given that, you certainly would have access to the current (old) version of their local database, so it would be up to you to build in any migration/upgrade functionality as part of the app.

Comment: Thank you. There is a suitable way to the migration only the first time app is running and taking account what version is being updated? For example, if the user has **version1** installed and he only updates the app when **version3** is currently available I will probably need to a different migration than **version2->version3**

Comment: good point yes, I'd say that's the case. You may be able to work a background task into this as well, but that doesn't get you out of having to account for skipped updates.

Comment: well, I was asking if there is some mechanism/event/callback that gets executed when updating an app that I can use instead of implementing my own

Comment: ah, I don't believe so given the guidance that's used for [application data versioning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464917.aspx#Application_data_storage)